# Application does not load start activity on Android 2.3.7

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been developing app on Android SDK version 19 and running it on emulator/phone 4.4.2 without a problem.

Then i set minSdkVersion to 8 (both in build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml), rebuilt succesfully but when started on emulator with Android 2.3.7 i get:

```
    02-09 03:08:48.383    1546-1546/? E/AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cz.xxx.appname/cz.xxx.appname.ui.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.xxx.appname.ui.HomeActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/cz.xxx.appname-2.apk]
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.xxx.appname.ui.HomeActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/cz.xxx.appname-2.apk]
                at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The application always crashes on start. Same build runs on 4.2.2 succesfully.

Do you have any idea what causes this issue?

Thanks,
endokr

Comment: Can you breakpoint it on the first line of OnCreate or does it fail before?

Comment: please post the log stacktrace. It helps in quickly solving the error

Comment: Id does not step into MainActivity OnCreate. Stacktrace appended.

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be that, you are using component in your activity layout not exists in the older version of APIs (2.3.6 in your case) like for example switch button so check the components in your activity layout.

Comment: I'm actually using switches that appears to be in Android 4.0+ but I thought that kind of error would be presented differently.

And also the switch is not on the main activity.

Comment: you can share with me your activity layout if you like and we will look on it together

Comment: All of a sudden, Android Studio underlined classes that are not supported in API version 8 (LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks & ActionBar.TabListener). So you were right, thanks.