# My Application is running fine on Android 4.4 but crashes on 2.3. Not even starting

Tags: android

The below one is the source code.
This program just does the memory match game and works very well in android 4.4
    package com.example.myimagematchgamev10;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

class MyCustomImageButton extends ImageButton
{
    protected int holdingImage;

    public MyCustomImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.holdingImage = -1;
    }
    public MyCustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.holdingImage = -1;
    }
    public MyCustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.holdingImage = -1;
    }
}
//public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Random myR = new Random ();
    MyCustomImageButton[] myImageButtons;
    int[] myImages={R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.five,R.drawable.seven,R.drawable.eight,R.drawable.six,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four};
    int[] myImageButtonArray = {R.id.imageButton0, R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2, R.id.imageButton3, R.id.imageButton4,
            R.id.imageButton5, R.id.imageButton6, R.id.imageButton7, R.id.imageButton8, R.id.imageButton9,
            R.id.imageButton10, R.id.imageButton11, R.id.imageButton12, R.id.imageButton13, R.id.imageButton14,
            R.id.imageButton15};

    // The following four lies for holding temp data while checking the match
    int myFirstButtonImage = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    int mySecondButtonImage = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    ImageButton myFirstButton = null;
    ImageButton mySecondButton = null;

    // for message box
    int myNoOfClick = 0;
    int myNoOfCompletedCells = 0;

    Button myNewgame;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog; // =  new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    protected void initializeGrid()
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            myImageButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            myImageButtons[i].setClickable(true);
            myImageButtons[i].holdingImage = -1;
        }
        myNoOfClick = 0;
        myNoOfCompletedCells = 0;
    }

    protected void createGrid()
    {
        myImageButtons = new MyCustomImageButton[16];
        for (int i=0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            myImageButtons[i] = (MyCustomImageButton) findViewById(myImageButtonArray[i]);

        }
    }

    protected void loadImages()
    {
        int myNextInt;
        for (int i=0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < 2; ++j)
            {
                myNextInt = myR.nextInt(16);
                while (myImageButtons[myNextInt].holdingImage != -1)
                {
                    myNextInt = myR.nextInt(16);
                }
                if(myImageButtons[myNextInt].holdingImage == -1)
                {
                    myImageButtons[myNextInt].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    myImageButtons[myNextInt].holdingImage = myImages[i];
                    //myGridValues[myNextInt] = i+1;
                    // myMap.put(myImageButtonArray[myNextInt],myImages[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }


    protected void showMessage()
    {
        alertDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        //alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
        alertDialog.setMessage("No. Of clicks are:  " + myNoOfClick +" !");
        alertDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createGrid();
        initializeGrid();
        loadImages();;

        myNewgame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
        myNewgame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initializeGrid();
                loadImages();
            }
        });


        for(int i=0; i<myImageButtons.length; ++i)
        {
            final MyCustomImageButton myTempImageButton = myImageButtons[i];
            //final int myIBId = myTempImageButton.getId();
            myTempImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                //@Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ++myNoOfClick;
                    myTempImageButton.setBackgroundResource(myTempImageButton.holdingImage);
                    if (myFirstButtonImage == R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    {
                        if(mySecondButtonImage == R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        {
                            myFirstButtonImage = myTempImageButton.holdingImage;
                            myFirstButton = myTempImageButton;
                            myTempImageButton.setClickable(false);
                            myNoOfCompletedCells += 2;
                            if (myNoOfCompletedCells >= 16)
                            {
                                showMessage();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myFirstButton.setClickable(true);
                            mySecondButton.setClickable(true);
                            myFirstButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            mySecondButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                            myFirstButton = myTempImageButton;
                            myFirstButtonImage = myTempImageButton.holdingImage;
                            myTempImageButton.setClickable(false);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myTempImageButton.setClickable(false);
                        if (myFirstButtonImage == myTempImageButton.holdingImage)   // For Success full Match
                        {
                            myFirstButton.setClickable(false);
                            myFirstButtonImage = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                            mySecondButtonImage = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mySecondButton = myTempImageButton;
                            mySecondButtonImage = myTempImageButton.holdingImage;
                            myFirstButtonImage = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }


}




The above is the source file
```

I have the following in manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myimagematchgamev10"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myimagematchgamev10.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The above one is the manifest xml

The below is the log I am getting

Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd AVD_for_Nexus_S -netspeed full -netdelay none

Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is online: emulator-5554
Target device: AVD_for_Nexus_S [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: D:\Android\MyApplicationProject\MyImageMatchgameV1.0Project\MyImageMatchgameV1.0\build\apk\MyImageMatchgameV1.0-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.myimagematchgamev10
Installing com.example.myimagematchgamev10
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.myimagematchgamev10"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.myimagematchgamev10
Success

Launching application: com.example.myimagematchgamev10/com.example.myimagematchgamev10.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.example.myimagematchgamev10/com.example.myimagematchgamev10.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myimagematchgamev10/.MainActivity }

Comment: Easy. LogcatNotFoundException.

Comment: @Enrichman haha Nice one.

Comment: @Enrichman could also be LogcatNotPostedException ;-)

Comment: trolls, lol ... point is that you should post logcat

Comment: targetSdkVersion="10"    o_O

Comment: Check this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657123/application-does-not-load-start-activity-on-android-2-3-7/21657424#21657424

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell without the logs, you are using an API that was introduced after Gingerbread.

Just read the LogCat, it should give you hints on the exact function that's not working.

Comment: Can you please let me know where to see the log? I am totally new to Android development and new the the editor as well. I am using Android studio.

Comment: Launching application: com.example.myimagematchgamev10/com.example.myimagematchgamev10.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.example.myimagematchgamev10/com.example.myimagematchgamev10.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myimagematchgamev10/.MainActivity }
[1]   Segmentation fault      am start -n "com...